# Delphi: check if Record of DataSet is visible or filtered

Tags: delphi, filter, dataset

At work we have a component called a "ClientdatasetGrid",
which allows the user to sort the records of the grid by clicking on one or multiple column-titles.

I have made a component for work also, a descendant from TEdit, which I call TDBFilterEdit.

once you assign a DataSet or DBGrid to it, it creates an OnFilterRecord event for the DataSet and after you stop changing the text that Event is executed.

the problem arises whenever the Dataset is already filtered and the user sorts the grid.

the grid-component adds IndexDefs to the Clientdataset by first deleteing the current IndexDef, Updating, Adding the new Index and updating again.

whenever an index is deleted or added my OnFilterRecord event is triggered.
I mitigated this by disableing controls and NIL-ing the OnFilterRecord event from inside the grid until the new index is added.

```
cds.DisableControls();
try
  extProc:=nil;  
  if (TMethod(cds.OnFilterRecord).Code<>nil) and (TMethod(cds.OnFilterRecord).Data<>nil) then 
  begin
    TMethod(extProc):=TMethod(cds.OnFilterRecord);
    cds.OnFilterRecord:=nil;
  end; 
  ...
  ...  //<-- Delete Index & create new Index
  ...
finally
  cds.OnFilterRecord:=extProc;
  cds.EnableControls();  
end;
```

Once the Event is assigned again, it is immeadeately called and is iterating through all X records even though the user may only see 5.

Now I am searching for a way to see if a record is already filtered out so I can skip it inside my filter-method if the text hasn't changed.

---

Edit: Since a MVCE has been demanded I'll post a short version of my OnFilterRecord procedure.

- the following procedure is executed everytime the component hasn't recieved an input for 1 second
- fStringtypes and fTimeTypes are both a set of TFieldType
- fStringTypes:=[ftString,ftMemo,ftFMTMemo,ftFixedChar,ftWideString];
- fTimeTypes:=[ftDate,ftTime,ftDateTime,ftTimeStamp];
- after the procedure is completely finished the timer is disabled and controls are enabled again.

  ```
  procedure TDBEditFilter.FilterRecords(DataSet:TDataSet; var Accept:Boolean);
  var
    ...
  begin
    //initiliaztion//
    s:=FilterText;  //Filtertext=User Input into the TDBEditFilters Textfield
    TestFloat:=0;    
    Accept:=False;
    /////////////////

    for i:=0 to fDBGrid.Columns.Count-1 do  //for all DBGrid-Columns
    begin           
      if fDataSet.FieldByName(fDBGrid.Columns[i].FieldName).DataType in fStringTypes then
      begin                 
        Strvalue:=fDataSet.FieldByName(fDBGrid.Columns[i].FieldName).AsString;

        Accept:=AnsiContainsText(Strvalue,s); //<--to ignore Upper/lowercase
      end
      else if fDataSet.FieldByName(fDBGrid.Columns[i].FieldName).DataType in fTimeTypes then  
      begin

         StrValue:=DateTimeToStr(fDataSet.FieldByName(fDBGrid.Columns[i].FieldName).As   DateTime,Local_Form_Settings);
        Accept:=Pos(StrValue,s)<>0;
      end
      else if fDataSet.FieldByName(fDBGrid.Columns[i].FieldName).DataType=ftBlob then
      begin
        //ignore Blob
      end
      else //whatever fieldtype is left must be a numeric Field-type like integer or float
      begin 
        if TryStrToFloat(s,TestFloat)=True then
        begin
          Accept:=(TestFloat=fDataSet.FieldByName(fDBGrid.Columns[i].FieldName).AsFloat);
        end;
      end;

      if Accept=True then break;  //stop checking this record and check next record
    end; 
  end;
  ```

Comment: I would wonder why not "if Assigned(cds.OnFilterRecord) then" and "extProc := cds.OnFilterRecord" instead of crunching the method. I also wonder how/why does your component iterate non-filtered records.

Comment: I tried "if assigned()" beforehand, but the compiler threw an error that it expected more parameters.

Comment: Is "ClientdatasetGrid" a custom component? Maybe you would be better off enhancing the component to hold a list of filtered records?

Comment: I thought about that already, that everytime I finish filtering I just switch out the result-sets, but I fear that this might be very memory-consuming after a few keyboard-inputs.

the grid itself is from an older open source code by Anders Ohlsson and John Kaster. by now SMComponents made a newer version that supports all kinds of data in the grid.

Comment: "Once the Event is assigned again [...]iterating through all X records"  That's just the way  CDS filtering works abd I think it would be v. hard to change because the filtering operation happens on tho "other side" of the IDSCursor interface, in Midas.Dll.  But if you are struggling with performance problems I think your TDBFilterEdit implementation is likely defective.

Comment: Btw I've voted to close this q as off-topic until it gets an MCVE.

Comment: Why is this question off topic?

the question is very direct and does not require a MVCE.
I wanted to know if I can somehow determine wether a record is already filtered out, that is all.

Comment: Save a bookmark, try to navigate after filtering, if you can't  then it's filtered out.

Comment: A TFilterRecord-Event is triggered automatically for each record in a Dataset IF the property Filtered=true And OnFilterRecord<>nil.

I don't iterate through all records once the event triggered, that is what the dataset does automatically. 

I wanted to know if there is a way for me to prevent the dataset from applying the Filter-Event on a record that is already filtered out.

as for your second question: My chef cares that the sorting takes longer now that the dataset also has to filter.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would post this as a separate answer because I've been experimenting
with a "Filter TEdit" that works in a similar way as I'm guessing yours does, and it doesn't
seem to exhibit any particular performance problems.  My main assumption is that you are using one filter TEdit per datafield of interest, rather that a single one into which the user types a compound Sql-like expression including the field names, comparison operators, etc.

The number of guesses I've had to make is why I said it would have been helpful for you to include an MCVE.

I've written it to be self-contained, i.e. it generates its own data instead of needing
an external database.

As you'll see if you try it, with a CDS containing, say, 3000 records,
the time to update the filters is a few tens of milliseconds (under 20 on my laptop).
If the CDS contains 30000 records, the filter update time increases roughly linearly
to about 200 ms which seems perfectly acceptable from a gui-responsivenes pov.

(Traditionally, TCDSs have been regarded as hitting a brick wall performance-wise when the number of records gets into the tens of thousands)

Note that for simplicity

a) I haven't used a DateTime fiield for BirthDate or whatever,
because of the complications of dealing with partial dates inputted by the user.

b) In the `OnFilterRecord` event, the LastName, FirstName and Age comparisons
are done by comparing the field as a string with the corresponding filter expression.

c) The Filter expressions, if non-blank are left- and right-padded with asterisks
and the value comparisons are done using the `MatchesMask` function from the Masks unit.
See `FilterExpr`.

d) The IndexDef's FieldNames are composed of the names of the fields for which
the filter edit's text is non-blank.

e) If the gui-updating is too slow if the user rapidly types several
characters in succession into the TEdits, you can work around this by
replacing the TEdits' OnChange event code by code in their KeyUp event
which enables a TTimer which has an interval of, say, 150 ms.  Then, in its OnTimer, call `UpdateFilter`.

Code:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    CDS1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    CDS1ID: TIntegerField;
    CDS1Age: TIntegerField;
    CDS1LastName: TStringField;
    CDS1FirstName: TStringField;
    edLastNameFilter: TEdit;
    edFirstNameFilter: TEdit;
    edAgeFilter: TEdit;
    procedure CDS1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
    procedure edLastNameFilterChange(Sender: TObject);  //  Set the OnChange events for the
    //  FirstName and Age TEdits to this, too
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure Log(const Title, Msg: String);
    function FilterExpr(const Input: String): String;
  protected
  public
    LastNameFilter,
    FirstNameFilter,
    AgeFilter : String;
    IndexFields : String;
    IndexDef : TIndexDef;
    procedure UpdateFilterExprsAndIndex;
    procedure UpdateFilter;
  end;

[...]
rocedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
  Ch1,
  Ch2 : Char;
  LastName,
  FirstName : String;
  Age : Integer;
begin
  CDS1.CreateDataSet;
  CDS1.DisableControls;
  try
    for i := 1 to 30000 do begin
      Ch1 := Chr(Ord('a') + random(26));
      Ch2 := Chr(Ord('a') + random(26));
      LastName:= StringOfChar(Ch1, 1 + Random(10));
      FirstName := StringOfChar(Ch2, 1 + Random(10));
      Age := Trunc(Random(71));
      CDS1.InsertRecord([i, LastName, FirstName, Age]);
    end;
  finally
    CDS1.First;
    CDS1.EnableControls;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Log(const Title, Msg : String);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Title + ' : ' + Msg);
end;

procedure TForm1.CDS1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := True;
  if LastNameFilter <> '' then
    Accept := MatchesMask(CDS1LastName.AsString, LastNameFilter);
  if not Accept then exit;

  if FirstNameFilter <> '' then
    Accept := Accept and MatchesMask(CDS1FirstName.AsString, FirstNameFilter);
  if not Accept then exit;

  if AgeFilter <> '' then
    Accept := Accept and MatchesMask(CDS1Age.AsString, AgeFilter);
end;

procedure TForm1.edLastNameFilterChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpdateFilter;
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateFilter;
var
  T1 : Integer;
begin
  T1 := GetTickCount;
  UpdateFilterExprsAndIndex;
  CDS1.DisableControls;
  try
    CDS1.Filtered := False;
    if (edLastNameFilter.Text <> '') or (edFirstNameFilter.Text <> '') or (edAgeFilter.Text <> '') then begin
      CDS1.Filtered := True;
    end;
    if IndexFields <> '' then
      CDS1.IndexDefs[0].Fields := IndexFields;  //  Warning: This IndexDef needs to exist
    Log('Filter update time', IntToStr(GetTickCount - T1) + 'ms');
  finally
    CDS1.EnableControls;
  end;
end;

function TForm1.FilterExpr(const Input : String) : String;
begin
  Result := Input;
  if Result <> '' then
    Result := '*' + Result + '*';
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateFilterExprsAndIndex;
begin
  LastNameFilter := FilterExpr(edLastNameFilter.Text);
  FirstNameFilter := FilterExpr(edFirstNameFilter.Text);
  AgeFilter := FilterExpr(edAgeFilter.Text);

  IndexFields := '';
  if LastNameFilter <> '' then
    IndexFields := 'LastName';
  if FirstNameFilter <> '' then begin
    if IndexFields <> '' then
      IndexFields := IndexFields + ';';
    IndexFields := IndexFields + 'FirstName';
  end;
  if AgeFilter <> '' then begin
    if IndexFields <> '' then
      IndexFields := IndexFields + ';';
    IndexFields := IndexFields + 'Age';
  end;
end;
```

I hope this at least gives you a basis for comparison with your own
code so that you can identify any bottlenecks.

**Update** Rather to my surprise, I found that with the compound filter expression I used for testing, it is **much** faster to set the CDS's `Filter` to the expression and leave it do to the filtering using `OnFilterRecord`,  With 30000 records,  `UpdateFilter2` takes under 20 ms, compared with 200 ms for a similar expression set using the `UpdateFilter'.

```
procedure TForm1.btnSetFilterExprClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edFilter.Text := 'LastName=''aaa'' and FirstName = ''zz'' and Age > 30 ';
  UpdateFilter2;
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateFilter2;
var
  T1 : Integer;
begin
  CDS1.OnFilterRecord := Nil;
  T1 := GetTickCount;
  CDS1.DisableControls;
  try
    CDS1.Filtered := False;
    CDS1.Filter := edFilter.Text;
    if CDS1.Filter <> '' then begin
      CDS1.Filtered := True;
    end;
    Log('Filter update time', IntToStr(GetTickCount - T1) + 'ms');
  finally
    CDS1.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It is pretty much like this, only I use a single "TEdit" for all the fields and instead of MatchesMask I use the Pos function.

I'll edit my Text to include my OnFilterRecord

Comment: @ViktorPagels: Then do you parse the user's input in the OnFilterRecord or what?  It is really time-wasting having to guess what you are doing:  **Why not just show your code**?

Comment: I tried using a text-based filter before, the problem is that it doesn't work on DateTime-Fields in a non-english environment.

I have opened a question about this before, because of that the idea of a new component sprung into existence.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163862/how-to-use-the-filter-functions-of-tclientdatasets-for-dates/42163972?noredirect=1#comment71536659_42163972

Comment: if you want I can copy and paste my entire Code but it won't make much difference, you have it already figured out how my component works.

it recieves a CM_TEXTCHANGED message, and sets the CDS.Filtered-property to true if its Text is<>''
According to embarcadero as soon as  the Filtered property is set to true
AND the OnFilterRecord-Event is assigned the OnFilterRecord event is executed.

Comment: @ViktorPagels:  I've posted an update to my answer to your q  stackoverflow.com/questions/42163862/…to show how to translation local-language date function names into the equivalents which are supported by a CDS.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you could do this using the standard TClientDataset's implementations
of indexing and filtering.

Changes to the index or filter on a TCDS both invoke a traversal of its data records
and you have no control over that because in both cases, the TCDS functionality depends
on calls into the interfaces provided by Midas.Dll.

Setting up a new or changed index involves calling `procedure TCustomClientDataSet.SortOnFields`
which in turn calls `Cursor.SortOnFields`, where `Cursor` is of type IDSCursor - see DSIntf.Pas

Equally, changing the CDS filter involves calling `TCustomClientDataSet.AddExprFilter`, which in
turn calls `FDSCursor.AddFilter`, where `FDSCursor` is again of type IDSCursor.

So, you would need to re-implement both of these at the Midas level, on the other side
of the IDSCursor interfave to avoid the default behaviour.

Comment: what a bummer, I suppose there is no easy way to look how midas.dll implements it and afterwards rewrite it?

I'll try the Bookmark method from Sertac Akyuz for now and after that I'll look into storing the Data-OleVariant.

Comment: ISTR recent Delphi versions come with the C++/obj files for Midal.Dll, but you should  really regard changing Midas as a very last resort.  Tbh, I think you would do far better to reconsider your TDBFilterEdit implementation:  have you done any serious profiling of it, using e.g. NexusDB's Quality Suite?

Comment: No I haven't yet as I lack such tools and I doubt that I'll get them authorized when it costs money. I could try to profile with my IDE.

my TDBFilterEdit implementation shouldn't be that inefficient. I iterate through each grid-column and check for the datatype of the fields and then just convert units and compare them with the user-input.

Comment: I think you really need to post an MCVE, because all sorts of things are not obvious from your description, e.g. how you determine which data field(s) your user's input applies to.

Comment: all the fields, and that is heavily dependent on the SQL.

Select * from Person for example with the fields 
AGE, NAME, BIRTHDAY in the Person table would yield those 3 fields. so naturally I have to compare the user-input against those 3 fields.

as soon as the Accept-variable is true for one record I stop any other comparisons for that record. I also don't have any initialization code in my filter-procedure, as any initialization is already taken care of beforehand.

Comment: @ViktorPagels:  See the separate answer I've just added.